# Shortest way to create custom RuntimeError with custom message?

Tags: ruby

Is there a shorter way to achieve the following?

```
 class InvalidEmail < RuntimeError
    def initialize(email) @email = email; end
    def to_s; "'#{@email}' is an invalid email"; end
 end
```

Note: The custom message must include the failing email.

### UPDATE

@fylooi's answer gave me the idea to create a factory class to achieve what I want.  The client code below is just what I imagined, though the factory implementation could probably be simplified:

```
class CustomError
  def self.new(msg)
    Class.new(RuntimeError) do
      def initialize(*args)
        @args = args
      end
      define_method(:to_s) do
        @args.each.with_index.reduce(msg) do |m,(x,i)|
          m.gsub(Regexp.new("\\{#{i}}"), x)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# CLIENT CODE   
InvalidEmail = CustomError.new('"{0}" is an invalid email')

puts InvalidEmail.new('hi')
```

Comment: `raise` without an exception class is itself a `RuntimeError`.  So you could just do `raise "#{email} is an invalid email"`.

Comment: I want the custom error class though.  so question is to rewrite my example keeping both the custom class and the custom message, but with less boilerplate

Comment: Why would you want it any shorter than that? It would just compromise readability.

Comment: @user81269, Ask yourself: What information is needed to specify my custom error?  1. The error's class name (`InvalidEmail`).  2. The string message 3. Something to refer to the argument passed in.  That information can fit comfortably on a single line.  Everything else is boilerplate and distraction.  If you think boilerplate helps readability, you need to readjust your entire understanding of what readability is.

Comment: An exception class is a bit more. You should care about the hierarchy as well, when creating an exception class. Maybe you want to explicitly rescue from `InvalidEmail`, but maybe you'll want to rescue from `ValidationError` and you would like to make sure that InvalidEmail, InvalidFirstName, InvalidAnything is caught at one place. So the class hierarchy is also important for your exception. What you choose to ignore, is actually there to help you.

Comment: If you think inheritance is a good thing, we aren't going to agree on anything design related.

Comment: Let's not forget that we're talking about exceptions. Nobody thinks inheritance is a good things.

Comment: You _just_ brought up that caring about the inherticance hierarchy of my exceptions is a reason that I should embrace the boilerplate.  Setting aside the fact that the two things are orthoganal concerns so your comment was misplaced either way, the comment was implicitly assuming a design of exceptions that embrace inheritance.

Comment: Let's take a step back. In your previous comment you asked the following question: What information is needed to specify my custom error?
I was trying to make the point that the exception class from which your custom error inherits from is crucially important.

Comment: And I was making the point that no, it's not.  Because I won't have an inheritance hierarchy because it is terrible design.

Comment: When writing exception classes in ruby why would you not take into consideration how `rescue` works?

Comment: I don't even know what that means.  The fact that `rescue` supports an inheritance based style of design does not mean it's a good idea to use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135013/discussion-between-user81269-and-jonah).

Answer (score 0):

This might save a few line breaks. I would keep the line breaks though.

```
InvalidEmail = Class.new(RuntimeError) { attr_accessor :email; def to_s; "'#{@email}' is an invalid email"; end }
```

Comment: This always results in `'' is an invalid email` no matter what you pass in as the `email`.

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that usage is a bit different. You need to set `exception.email = @email` outside the constructor.

Comment: i'm not crazy about that.  It should be a single step to construct, and the object should be immutable.

Comment: Then just replace the `attr_accessor` with `def initialize(email); ... ; end;`. Becomes mostly the same as your initial implementation.

Comment: `to_s` and `@email = email` can be generalized and extracted to a base class, in which case this class would become `InvalidEmail = Class.new(SimpleError) { def initialize(object, message); super; end }`. Wouldn't bother for just one class though. For that matter, even `initialize` doesn't need to be there.

Comment: yeah, that was basically my idea.  ofc it isn't for just one class, but for creating many custom errors (but with a simple shared structure) for an application.